# Position textview below list & reposition it as size of list increases

Tags: android, listview, layout, textview, position

In my layout, I have a textview which I need to be fixed at the top of the screen, a button to be fixed at the bottom of the screen. 
Between these two, I have a list with a textview(with a drawable) below it. (please see image). I want the textview positioned below the list;i.e.; as list items grow, the textview should reposition itself. As I click on the textview, I add items to the list. I am able to achieve this, but as my list items increase, the textview goes below the list & is not visible. So what I see on screen is the top textview with the list below it & the bottom button. The textview to add items in list view is not visible, so I cannot add items to my list. I need that even if the list items increase, I want the list to be visible along with the textview.i.e.; **as list items grow, the textview should reposition itself**. I tried various approaches suggested with several combinations of linear & relative layouts & positioning techniques, but I am not able to achieve this. [image]

Comment: Use RelativeLayout and set TextView below the ListView

Comment: Your question is terribly hard to read and understand...

Comment: Sjd : this does not work. I tried it. The textview hides as the list items increase.

Comment: potAito : what hard did you feel in it ? I have also added my layout image for you to understand.

Comment: @AndroidGuy I'm not downvoting your question. Could you illustrate what you want with another image of what it should look like? You could hardcode that for the time being and make another screenshot or just use paint/inkscape or something like that :)

Comment: @AndroidGuy Also add a short description to your current image so we know if this is what you currently have or what you want or what you don't want..

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="abc xyz"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button"></ListView>

<TextView
    android:layout_below="@+id/lv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Save"
    android:id="@+id/button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to nest the layouts here. You could for example use a LinearLayout with vertical orientation as parent and place your textview and listview (or whatver you are using for your item list) inside the LinearLayout. Here's the idea:

> -TopView: set to wrap content
>
> -ListView: set to fill parent
>
> -TextView: Set to wrap content

If I'm not mistaken this should set the top and bottom view to fixed sizes and make the ListView fill the remaining space.

Comment: I don't want the textview (with + image) at a fixed position, but it should position itself as list items increase. As you can see in the image, there is 1 item in the list, so the textview is at the top, but if the list has 4-5 items, the textview should reposition just above the "Save" button & the list should scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding that button with image as footer to the listview  it will work with less noumber of items when it exceed the screen hight remove footer and make the bottom layout visible(Have to add the same footer item in bottom layout also).